# Mechanize select ids with suffix

Tags: ruby, mechanize

i'm trying to scrape some urls on a page with mechanize. I use `link_with(:id=>'')`. Each `id` have the same name but a different number suffix. My code

```
require 'mechanize'
m = Mechanize.new
results = m.get(website_url)
listing_link = results.link_with(:id => "listing-1234-56")
click_link = listing_link.click
```

How can i click on each link with `id="listing-XXXX-XX"` ? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
results.link_with(:id => /^listing-/)
```

Comment: i have `undefined method 'click'` with `listing_link = search_results.links_with(:id => /^listing-/) ; click_link = listing_link[0].click`

Comment: It's a single link so leave the [0] off.

Comment: same error i tried `listing_link = search_results.links_with(:id => /^listing-/) ; click_link = listing_link[0].click` and `listing_link = search_results.link_with(:id => /^listing-/) ; click_link = listing_link.click`

Comment: I tried on another website and it works, i think it's because my `id="listing"` is in a `div` and not in `<a>`